# error when spark sql read parquet table with text partition

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdp, hive-metastore

**1、Background:**

I have a hive external table A, which was created in text format when it was created.
The HDFS data of the partition is also text+gz.

Table A is used by thousands of sql.files.
All the 5-year historical partitions of Table A may be used.

Currently we have a better storage format parquet. To reduce switching costs
I plan to change table A to a parquet table, with parquet+gz data for the new partition and text+gz data for the old partition.
The business can read any partition of table A through sparksql and hivesql.

**2、Verification process:**

2.1、create Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UvvM.png)

2.2、add partition

20210702 path is text+gz

20210703 path is parquet+gz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfG95.png)

**3、Error:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaMo2.png)

**4、expect:**

Are there some solutions, such as parameter configuration, that can solve this problem.

What I have done:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24965
According to the stack information reported in the error, I have not seen sparksql in the source code about the hive table metadata and partition metadata.

**5、Configuration Environment:**
hdp2.7.3
sparksql2.3
hive1.2